# Beanstalk cannot find Django application in subdirectory

Tags: django, github, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I'm playing around with Beanstalk to deploy a private website project. Currently, my project is organized in a Monorepo containing the frontend being vue.js and backend being Django. And looks like this:

```
-.ebextension
    -django.config
-.elasticbeanstalk
    -config.yml
-frontend
     -...
-backend
    -backend
        -settings.py
        -wgsgi.py
        -...
    -manage.py
    -...
```

At first, I deployed the backend from inside the backend directory which worked great, but now I'm trying to change that to trigger the deployment from GitHub. The CodePipeline works in principle except for the last step, wheres about to start the application where it fails because it cannot find the application, as it is in a subdirectory. How can I reference the WSGIPath in a subdirectory?
I tried now many combinations like `./backend/backend.wsgi` etc. But not one is accepted.

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
      WSGIPath: backend/backend.wsgi:application <--Not found
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
      DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: backend.settings


packages: 
  yum:
    python3-devel: []
    postgresql-devel: []

container_commands:
  00_list:
    command: "ls && ls backend/"
    leader_only: true
  01_start:
    command: "echo starting initialization"
  02_makemigrations:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/activate && cd backend/ && python manage.py makemigrations"
    leader_only: true
  02_migrate:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/activate && cd backend/ && python manage.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: hey, I'm having the exact same problem. Did you manage to solve it somehow?

Comment: try using `backend.backend.wsgi:application` for `WSGIPath`. Also you need to set the uwsgi path in your Elastic Beanstalk environment in AWS console.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this via the CodePipeline and the corresponding buildspec.yml where you can specifiy an output directory

```
env:
  variables:
    FRONT_URL: 'http://localhost:8000/'

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo "Before running tests"
      - cd backend/
      - pip install -r requirements.txt
  build:
    commands:
      - echo "Running all unit tests"
      - python manage.py test
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*' <--- use all files
  base-directory: 'backend' <--normally for specifiying the build output dir, in this case it's my backend dir
```